# GraphQL + Java How to get Query String in Query Resolver class?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am able to start Spring Boot GraphQL Java Server (with GraphiQL as User Interface to run query). Now I am trying to get the **query string** passed from the GraphiQL (actually the query in payload sent to /graphql endpoint) into the Query Resolver class. I tried different options but nothing helped.

```
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
...
public Iterable<Book> findAllBooks() {
    String query = ** WHAT TO DO?? **
    return bookRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a query with parameters,then write the java code in GraphQLQueryResolver

E.g:

Schema

```
type Query{
  findBookByTitle(title:String!):Book!
}
```

Resolver

```
public Book findBookByTitle(String title){
  //you can get the title
}
```

Comment: I can run the application, send query and get response back. Here I am trying to get the actual query inside the Query.finaAllBooks() method. For Example if my query is: {
  findAllBooks {
    id
    isbn
    title
    pageCount
    author {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}  then in my actual question String query has this.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript I have found the full query via `info.operation.selectionSet.loc.source.body`.
and `info` comes from https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#resolver-arguments